# AirPods blinking orange as long as they are both in the case, one of the pods don’t work

Tags: iphone, ios, airpods

My AirPods keep blinking orange. When I take one out and shut the case, on opening it back it’s a stable green, if I return the pod back it starts blinking orange again, and if I connect to my device only the right pod works. I’ve tried to reset with the button at the back of the case to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Try wipe off the metal end of the problematic AirPod, and then used a Q-tip to clean the bottom of the case where the metal end of the AirPod made contact with the case. If this doesn’t work..well... contact Apple to advise that your product is not working properly upon receipt:

```
•   http://www.apple.com/contact/
•   Contact - Official Apple Support
•   https://twitter.com/applesupport
•   http://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/airpods/comments/btumr0/fix_for_those_stuck_on_flashing_amber/) and those instructions seemed to work for me. The key part was to unpair the AirPods, put them back in the case, close the case, and *leave it that way for 30 minutes*. After that time I re-opened the case and the light turned green!

To be safe I proceeded to reset them as instructed, then re-paired, and voila! Success.

Hope this helps others.